# Problems with parsing xml

Tags: python, xml, csv, lxml

I have some code that is parsing an xml file and saving it as a csv. I can do this two ways, one by manually downloading the xml file and then parsing it, the other by taking the xml feed directly using ET.fromstring and then parsing. When I go directly I get data errors it appears to be an integrity issue. I am trying to include the xml download in to the code, but I am not quite sure the best way to approach this.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import urllib

url = 'http://www.capitalbikeshare.com/data/stations/bikeStations.xml'
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read()

#I need code here!!!

tree = ET.parse('bikeStations.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#for child in root:
    #print child.tag, child.attrib

locations = []

for station in root.findall('station'):
    name = station.find('name').text
    bikes = station.find('nbBikes').text
    docks = station.find('nbEmptyDocks').text
    time = station.find('latestUpdateTime').text
    sublist = [name, bikes, docks, time]
    locations.append(sublist)
    #print 'Station:', name, 'has', bikes, 'bikes and' ,docks, 'docks'

#print locations

s = open('statuslog.csv', 'wb')
w = csv.writer(s)   
w.writerows(locations)
s.close()

f = open('filelog.csv', 'ab')
w = csv.writer(f)   
w.writerows(locations)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
```

and omit the line of: `tree = ET.parse('bikeStations.xml')`

As the response from `connection.read()` returns **String**, you can directly read the XML string by using **fromstring** method, you can read more from [HERE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml).